# Solving Matrix equation over GF(2) in Sage

Tags: linear-algebra, sage

I am trying to solve a system of linear equations in Sage. However, I want to print the solution only if it is unique. I have tried using `A.solve_right(y)` where `A is coefficient matrix`, `y is the right hand side (Ax = y)`. However, this returns a solution when there are multiple solutions. I tried checking if the determinant is 0, but this only works when having square matrix.

I have been thinking of 2 ways, but could not find suitable way to implement my thoughts in Sage:

1. Method which solves system of `n` equations of `m` variables. Whenever I call A.solve(x) where A is n x m matrix and x is vector of length n, I should get either exception "`No unique solution"` (if no or more than one solution) or the solution if it is unique.
2. Method which allows me adding rows to the matrix `A`. When I add new row I check if it is linear combination of the previous rows and if so I ignore that row. Otherwise, I add the new row. When I obtain a `n x n matrix A`, then I check if the `determinant is not zero` and print the solution. Otherwise I throw exception `"No unique solution"`.

I have been looking for solution online, but without success. I guess there must be some easy way to achieve this, but I am having short deadline and could not go deeply into the Sage documentation. Any suggestion will be very welcome!

Comment: Quick search of the sage docs shows matrix.echelon_form() . This will show you which columns are linear combinations of others.

Comment: @DavidMaust thanks. I was thinking that maybe it was implemented already, but now I did it that way, going through the rows and checking which ones are only zeros.

Answer (score 2):

With galois (python), you can find the rref of your matrix with

```
import galois
GF = galois.GF(2)
g = GF(x=matrix.astype(int))
g.row_reduce()
```

Comment: is there any link with Galois in python? I just wanted to learn more, like the `import galois`.
thanks and have a great corona-free week!

Comment: Not sure what do you mean? Galois is a Library for Python and can be installed via pip install galois